# Flower running the server and clients on different machines

Tags: federated-learning

I use [Flower API](https://flower.dev/) for federated learning applications. Is there any way to run the server and clients on different machines for a real-world benchmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, you can set up the server script and run it giving it an ip address and port:

```
fl.server.start_server(server_address="[SERVER_IP]:[PORT]",
    config=fl.server.ServerConfig(num_rounds=3), strategy=strategy)
```

And start the client with:

```
fl.client.start_numpy_client(server_address="[SERVER_IP]:[PORT]", client=ModelClient())
```

If you are on a LAN you can find the ipv4 of your computer with ipconfig on cmd.